# XSL - How do you capitalize first letter

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following xml.

```
<Name>
  <First>john</First>
  <Last>smith</Last>
</Name>
```

I want to capitalize first letter and out put in following formate.

```
 <FullName>John Smith</FullName>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [functx:capitalize-first](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_capitalize-first.html)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**I. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <FullName><xsl:apply-templates/></FullName>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="First|Last">
  <xsl:sequence select=
  "concat(upper-case(substring(.,1,1)),
          substring(., 2),
          ' '[not(last())]
         )
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Name>
    <First>john</First>
    <Last>smith</Last>
</Name>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<FullName>John Smith</FullName>
```

---

**II. XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vLower" select=
 "'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vUpper" select=
 "'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <FullName><xsl:apply-templates/></FullName>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="First|Last">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "concat(translate(substring(.,1,1), $vLower, $vUpper),
          substring(., 2),
          substring(' ', 1 div not(position()=last()))
         )
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'd recommend the use of `xsl:element` to create the `FullName` elements in the output (might require to set the output format to `xml` explicitly).

Comment: @JoelBodenmann, the main or even only use-case for the `<xsl:element>` instruction is to give us the ability to create elements with names that are **not** statically known. This is not the case here. When used beyond its goal, the `<xsl:element>` instruction only makes the code unreadable and slower. So, how would you justify your recommendation?

Comment: I'm fairly new to XSL. Until you mentioned it I didn't actively think about the use case of `xsl:element` for dynamic content "only". After doing more research and re-thinking your statement there's not much left here for me to argue with :)

Comment: @JoelBodenmann In this case I would recommend the available Pluralsights video-training on XSLT and XPath to get a systematic, fundamental knowledge of this subject

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
concat(
  translate(
    substring($Name, 1, 1),
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
  ),
  substring($Name,2,string-length($Name)-1)
)
```

Answer (score -2):

concat(
upper-case(substring($Name,1,1)),
substring($Name,2,string-length($Name))
)

Comment: Why are you repeating an answer already given (more that a decade ago).